# Background property on custom compound control

Tags: java, android, controls

I have a compound control that essentially combines a `Button` with a `ProgressBar`. It includes a background property that I have declared in *attrs.xml* as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyControl">
        <attr name="background" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

In the constructor of my control, I then pull the background out of the `TypedArray` and apply it.

All this worked fine until recently, when I had to add in a dependency on the v4 support library. Now I get this build error in my *attrs.xml* file:

> Error APT0000: Attribute "background" has already been defined (APT0000)

Why is this? And what can I do as an alternative so that consumers of my compound control can set the background?

Answer (score 0):

It's a conflict with an internal library that also defines the 'background' attribute.
For more details visit : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/actionbarsherlock/_N0hn47zx6w

Answer (score 0):

The attribute "background" has already been defined in the support library. So you dont have to define that again. you just add the attribute without defining it, like this,

If you want to use app:background in the custom view, then
`<attr name="background"/>` is enough in the attrs file.

If you want to use android:background in the custom view, then use this line in attrs.

```
<attr name="android:background"/>
```

Comment: Putting `<attr name="background"/>` in my _attrs.xml_ is exactly what I was trying, and what is giving me the compilation error.